# Grunt linking to node_modules

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have my project and have installed grunt. However in my node_modules folder I now have hundreds of symlinked folders instead of just the node modules I have requested. Why is this?

[Symlink modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA6YE.png)

Answer (score 0):

that happen with me but I never stop to check out why, because I ignore this folder using gitignore so that folder just stays in my local machine.

but why you are so worried?

looks like a bug check this: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3958

Comment: Not worried, but I wanted to check out why